# How can I add a web reference without the web service URL?

Tags: web-services, wsdl

Basically, I have a regenerated wrapper code for a web service that I need to use; when I run this, it works perfectly and receives the data from web service.

How can I add an already regenerated code from a .wsdl file to another Visual Studio solution as a web service?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you should be doing all new web service development (both client and server) using WCF. You should use "Add Service Reference" instead of "Add Web Reference".

In either case, simply give the file system path to the .WSDL file.

Comment: How can we add .wsdl file in vs2005? there is no "Add Service Reference" how to use it?

Comment: You use "Add Web Reference" in VS2005, and you should upgrade. You're very far behind the times. You're about to be _three_ revisions out of date.

Comment: @john_Saunders ya I know I am working on old version. but our product running on old version. I get ur point. Thanks

Comment: You can develop for .NET 2.0 using Visual Studio 2010. Also, in terms of what version your code runs on, be aware that .NET 3.5 is just .NET 2.0 SP2 plus some new libraries. If you don't use the new libraries, there is no reason to not upgrade to .NET 3.5. This way, some of your code could slowly begin to use the new libraries.